# Asking for two integer values in Java and throwing errors

Tags: java

I have this code. It asks for two integer values. If the first number is not an integer, then it throws an exception and asks the number again. My code works but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this:

```
boolean validInput = false;
boolean validInput2 = false;

while (validInput == false) {
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the first number? ");
        int firstNum = scanner.nextInt();
        validInput = true;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("It's not an integer.");
    }
}

while (validInput2 == false) {
    try {
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the second number? ");
        int secondNum = scanner2.nextInt();
        scanner2.close();
        validInput2 = true;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("It's not an integer.");
    }
}
```

I suppose I can do something like this as well. Right?

```
while (validInput == false) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is the first number? ");
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int firstNum = scanner.nextInt();
        validInput = true;
    }
}
```

In the second example when the `hasNextInt()` method is called, the scanner waits for a value, that makes sense, and if the condition becomes true, `nextInt()` is called, but `nextInt()` doesn't wait for input anymore. How does `nextInt()` know what the entered value was when the condition executed?

Comment: This sounds like it may be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Keep the scanner object outside the loop, just instantiate once.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would do it:

```
int firstNum;
int secondNum;
String num;
String errMsg = "Invalid Input - Integer Only!";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    System.out.print("What is the first number? ");
    num = scanner.nextLine();
    if (num.matches("\\d+")) {
        firstNum = Integer.parseInt(num);
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(errMsg);
}       

while (true) {
    System.out.print("What is the second number? ");
    num = scanner.nextLine();
    if (num.matches("\\d+")) {
        secondNum = Integer.parseInt(num);
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(errMsg);
}   

System.out.println();    
System.out.println("First Number:  --> " + firstNum);
System.out.println("eacond Number: --> " + secondNum);
```

For getting numerical input from a User, I prefer using the [Scanner.nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method in conjunction with the [String.matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method and a simple [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (["\\d+"](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#meta-characters)). You don't need to trap an exception this way. I just find it more flexible.

Declare your variables before the **while** loops, that way you can use them ***after*** the **while** loops or even within other **while** loops if you like. Break out of a loop once you've acquired and validated what you need.

Comment: Thank you but \\d+ matches double values as well. I only wanted it for integers.

Comment: @ZoltanKing - No, I'm afraid you are mistaken. It **does not** match double type values. Or do you mean it matches more than one integer digit?. If you want to deal with a single digit then remove the **+** character from the expression so that it is just **"\\d"**. Read up on [RegEx Metacharacters](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#meta-characters).

Answer (score 0):

After using `nextInt()`, you must clear the input buffer of the new line character still there from when the user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> by using `nextLine()` *before* trying `nextInt()` again, eg:

```
System.out.print("What is the first number? ");
int firstNum = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // <-- add this line
```

Still better would be to read the whole line in and parse it as an integer in one shot:

```
int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()); // do it in 1 line
```

Still better again is to write a reusable method that keeps trying to parse an integer, and if it doesn't read a valid integer, ask the user to retry (left to reader to implement).